# $\Delta_{0}$ formulas

Tags: set-theory

I am working through the Jech Set Theory book, and at the moment I am stuck at his definition of the $\Delta_{0}$ formulas: 
A formula of set theory is a $\Delta_{0}$ formula if:
(i) it has no quantifiers, or 
(ii) it is $\varphi \wedge \psi$, $\varphi \vee \psi$, $\neg \varphi$, $\varphi\rightarrow\psi$ or $\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$, with $\varphi$ and $\psi$ $\Delta_{0}$ formulas, or 
(iii) it is $(\exists x\in y)\varphi$ or $(\forall x\in y)\varphi$ where $\varphi$ a $\Delta_{0}$ formula.

I'm not really sure if I understand right $\Delta_{0}$ formula is.
In class we wrote the same, only in the first point $\varphi$ is $\Delta_{0}$ if it is atomic: $x\in y$, $x=y$.

Is a $\Delta_{0}$ formula hence only the combination of $x\in y$ or $x=y$ with (ii)?

Afterwards we have in the notes: $x=\mathscr{P}(y)$ is not $\Delta_{0}$.
Is that because $x=\mathscr{P}(y)\leftrightarrow (\forall u\in x)(u\subseteq y)\wedge (\forall u)(u\subseteq y\rightarrow u\in x)$ and then the part $\forall u$ is not writable like (i)?

Also some other papers about this definition would be helpful! Thanks, Luca

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions are the same. This is because omitting quantifiers effectively reduces the language to propositional calculus.

Namely, given atomic formulae, if we only apply (ii), we get exactly the quantifier-free formulae.

So the (i) of Jech basically amounts to what one can achieve with the (i) and (ii) from your class, without using (iii). As such, it is not minimal, but it does avoid tedious applications of (ii), when the actual interest in $\Delta_0$ formulae lies in the use of the restricted quantifications.

---

Regarding $x = \mathscr P(y)$, you are correct. More intuitively, since the definition of $\mathscr P(y)$ requires an unrestricted universal quantifier, it cannot be a $\Delta_0$ formula.

Unfortunately, Jech is the only source I have actually studied on the subject, so I can't help you with other references. I hope that the above clarified the definition a bit for you, though.

Comment: Yes thanks! That helped already. I'll try some more examples and see if I get a better feeling for it.